# How to prevent default submission when ALL required fields are filled in

Tags: javascript, html, forms, event-handling, dom-events

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="">
        <fieldset id="contactform">
            <legend>Contact Information</legend>
            <div id="name">
                <div class="info">
                    <label for="name">Name*<br><br></label>
                    <input type="text"  required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="email">
                <div class="info">
                    <label for="email"> Email*<br><br></label>
                    <input type="email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="msg">
                <div class="info">
                    <label for="message"> Your Message*<br><br></label>
                    <textarea required id="textarea" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea> 
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div id="sub">
                    <input id ="defaultsub" type="submit">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form> 
</div>
```

---

This is what I have so far and it prevents the default submission except it gets rid of the html5 validation. I was wondering how to have both in my code?

```
document.getElementById("defaultsub").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Prevent default submission");
    alert("ALERT!!!!!");
})
```

Comment: *I need it to prevent the default submission ONLY when ALL required fields are filled in*....really!!!

Comment: It's for my web assignment for school and it's really frustrating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know why you would want it to only prevent default submission when ALL required fields are filled IN.

But, since you asked, you can use the `document.querySelector('form')`[.checkValidity()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp) method which will check if the form is valid. In your case, you can use it like this

```
document.getElementById("defaultsub").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if(document.querySelector('form').checkValidity()){
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log("Prevent default submission");
     alert("ALERT!!!!!");
}
})
```

This will prevent default form submission ONLY if the form is **valid** (AKA if all required fields are filled in)

**EDIT:**

You might have to run the `checkValidity()` on the required INPUT elements instead of the whole FORM element for this tto work, which will take a little more time to write.

Comment: Yeah I know it doesn't make sense but that's what's required for my assignment. But thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! Good luck on your assignment :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, you need to check if any field is missing:

```
document.getElementById("defaultsub").addEventListener("click", function(event){
      var els = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea');
      let allFields=true;
      for(let i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
        if(!els[i].value.trim()){
          allFields=false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (allFields) {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.clear();
          console.log("Prevent default submission");
      }
    })
```